# TableView Display Issues - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a table view in Swift with headers that expand or contract to show or hide cells, but for some reason there are extra row dividers in the middle of the page for no reason, and the label in the header is not showing up.

[image]

```
class ExpandableHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    var section: Int = 0
    let expandLabel = UILabel()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // return number of section in table from data
        return list.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // return number of rows in each section from data
        return list[section].items.count + 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Create cell with the identifier which was set in the storyboard prototype cell

        // set cell data/name from our data object
        if indexPath.row < list[indexPath.section].items.count {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row].name
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custom", for: indexPath)
            return cell
        }

    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    // create a header of type of our subclassed header with section number
    let headerView = ExpandableHeader()

    headerView.expandLabel.text = "+"

    headerView.expandLabel.frame.size.height = 30
    headerView.expandLabel.frame.size.width = 30
    headerView.expandLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

    headerView.addSubview(headerView.expandLabel)

    headerView.expandLabel.frame.origin.x = view.frame.maxX - headerView.expandLabel.frame.width

    // assign selected/current section number to the header object
    headerView.section = section

    // create Gesture Recognizer to add ability to select header to this cutsom header with an action
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(headerClicked(sender:)))

    // add Gesture Recognizer to our header
    headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    return headerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    // check if row's section expanded parameter is set to true or false. set height of rows accordingly to hide or show them
    if list[indexPath.section].expanded == true {
        return 44
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

I added the relevant lines of code above. When you change the row height to 0, should the cell separator lines also be changed to height 0, or hidden?

Why is the header in each section not going all the way to the right side of the screen when the storyboard has it all the way to the right edge?
Is this also why the text label for the header is not being displayed? Because the right edge is getting cut off?

Sorry for the basic questions, I'm still getting the hang of this, so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: just write self.yourtableview.tableFooterView = UIView() in viewdidLoad

Comment: Is that to fix the random cell separators or to fix the text label in the table view cell that isn't being displayed because it's being cut off?

Answer (score 0):

To hide extra row divider use below lines of code

```
 let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
 self.tableView.tableFooterView = backgroundView //instead of tableView give your tableView name
```